# Downloads of large files fail without an error

Tags: http, iis-6, network-monitoring

We run professional websites on IIS 6 and have complaints of (and have verified) that downloads (via HTTP) from remote locations (e.g. Australia) are incomplete or truncated. This means the download completes without an error but the file is a fraction of the size and no error is returned to the client (downloads list shows full size 580MB, file system shows 70MB).

The interruption is somewhat unpredictable: sometimes it happens after 13min, sometimes after 30min, sometimes longer so a timeout seems unlikely.

Tests and workarounds:

Running a different web server (NginX) on the same server -> same error
Downloading via FTP on same server (using same IIS) -> no problem, always works
Downloading same file from different server (also IIS) -> sometimes the same error, sometimes works
We can't monitor the connections with Fiddler as it runs out of memory. Network experts could sniff but don't know what to look for.

Ideas? Tools?

UPDATE: Server Errors around the time of failure include:

1. A worker process with process id of '...' serving application pool '...' has requested a recycle because it reached its private bytes memory limit.
2. A process serving application pool '...' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '...'.

Comment: I would check out what microsoft calls "web garden", and see this answer - http://forums.iis.net/post/1955732.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately not an option for us as the session state would not be managed correctly within our application.